# IceFaces 1.8.2 "couldn't find container for property: bridge" on button click

Tags: java, icefaces

I have a two simple IceFaces buttons created this way. (I don't use xhtml but create things from Java code.)

```
HtmlCommandButton comp = new HtmlCommandButton();
comp.setId(id);
comp.setImmediate(immediate);
boolean clientSide = props.getBooleanValue("clientside", false);
if(clientSide) {
    comp.setOnclick(props.getValue("script") + ";return;");
} else {
    // ignore
}
```

I create two buttons this way: one with clientSide == true with a simple alert('hello'); script and one would run the attached javascript server side in a BSF box.

Thw two buttons are displayed, the clientSide button works with it's alert well. However when I click on the other button that has no onClick set programmatically, I get an error message in Firebug console (in IE9 as well):

```
uncaught exception: couldn't find container for property: bridge
```

I use ICEFaces 1.8.2. After Googling around I saw this error related to jsp:root tags, but I have no jsp in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button was rendered outside of the HTML form. That's all.. :-)